# Symfony BrowserKit Response how to get HTML content

Tags: symfony

is it possible to somehow get html from 
browserkit response?

Here is my dump:

```
object(Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response)#247 (3) {
  ["content":protected]=>
  string(47340) "1|#||4|25433|updatePanel|MainContent_UpdatePanel1|HTML_HERE......
  ["status":protected]=>
  int(200)
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Cache-Control"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "private"
    }
    ["Content-Type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(25) "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    }
    ["X-AspNet-Version"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "4.0.30319"
    }
    ["X-Powered-By"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "ASP.NET"
    }
    ["Date"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Wed, 22 Mar 2017 10:55:17 GMT"
    }
    ["Content-Length"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "47340"
    }
  }
}
```

I want somehow get HTML **content**
Is it possible? I googled and can't find it.

Thanks

//I tried it as array $response['content']. It doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried: `$response->getContent()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$response->getContent()
```

because Symfony BrowserKit Client use Symfony http-foundation Response, Please have a look to

[Symfony http-foundation Response](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Response.php#L412)

Comment: Some additional information would probably be useful.

Comment: Can you explain your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Comment: because Symfony BrowserKit Client use Symfony http Response ,

please have a look [getContent](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Response.php#L412)

Comment: @PeterTanath Please include that explanation in the answer so it can be easily found by anyone reading it.